# How to select a specific path for a savefiledialog in visual studios

Tags: vba, select, path, savefiledialog

I am stuck on how to make a specific path way to a certain folder when I save a image. I have no idea where to start or where to put the pathway within the command.
'I have recent put System.windows.forms. in and found it still worked'

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim savefiledialog1 As New SaveFileDialog

    Try

        savefiledialog1.FileName = "*.tif"

        savefiledialog1.Filter = "Tiff | *.tif"

        If savefiledialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            PictureBox1.Image.Save(savefiledialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work with following code:

```
savefiledialog1.InitialDirectory = "your/path"
```

More: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If you are saying to replace 'savefiledialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK' with 'savefiledialog1.InitialDirectory = "your/path" ' then the save button performs incomplete, it does not allow it to save or show the savefiledialog box.